# SQL using Nullif with substring and charindex

Tags: sql-server

please find below my SQL query - especially lines 7 and 8. I have a field called COMMENTS that might (might not) contain either a reference or a date. If either exists I want to extract that data into 'TEST' or 'Julia' respectively - I have done this and it works. However, the bit I am stumbling on is if a Ref or date does not exist in the COMMENTS field I would like NONE to appear. I have never worked with substring or charindex so I do not even know if this is possible. As you can see I have tried something with line 8 but this doesn't affect anything.If you think I can achieve this some other way - please advise.
Thank you.

```
SELECT T0.[DocDueDate], 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[NumAtCard],  
T0.[DocNum], 
T1.[ItemCode], 
T1.[Dscription], 
substring(t0.comments, charindex('.1', t0.comments)-5,8 ) AS 'TEST',
NULLIF(SUBSTRING(T0.COMMENTS, CHARINDEX('REF', T0.COMMENTS),11),'NONE') AS 'Julia'

FROM ODLN T0  INNER JOIN DLN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 

WHERE 
T0.[CardCode] = 'aa28' and  T0.[NumAtCard] Like 'SP%%%%%%%%%%%'
```

Comment: can you add some sample data and desired output, it usually helps in cases like this.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: How do I add data? I can't see an attachment option

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `ISNULL`. It is unclear what you want with `NULLIF`. Try this.

```
SELECT T0.[DocDueDate], 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[NumAtCard],  
T0.[DocNum], 
T1.[ItemCode], 
T1.[Dscription], 
substring(t0.comments, charindex('.1', t0.comments)-5,8 ) AS 'TEST',
ISNULL(SUBSTRING(T0.COMMENTS, CHARINDEX('REF', T0.COMMENTS),11),'NONE') AS 'Julia'

FROM ODLN T0  INNER JOIN DLN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 

WHERE 
T0.[CardCode] = 'aa28' and  T0.[NumAtCard] Like 'SP%%%%%%%%%%%'
```

Comment: Hi I'm afraid this did not work. The date pulls up (which is what needs to happen) but if there is no date the first 2 letters of the field and pulled through. I would like the date to show, but if there is no date to just leave the field blank. I am using Server 2012 when the Case statement doesn't seem to be valid

Comment: Can you post your Case statement?

Answer (score 0):

`NULLIF` will return `NULL` if the two parameters match, something which is never going to happen in your case, as the first parameter is 11 characters long.

I would use a `CASE` statement to arrive at your desired result - see if this works for you -

Unclear what your `LIKE` statement is doing with all those % signs...

```
SELECT 
    T0.[DocDueDate], 
    T0.[CardCode], 
    T0.[NumAtCard],  
    T0.[DocNum], 
    T1.[ItemCode], 
    T1.[Dscription], 
    substring(t0.comments, charindex('.1', t0.comments)-5,8 ) AS 'TEST',
    NULLIF(SUBSTRING(T0.COMMENTS, CHARINDEX('REF', T0.COMMENTS),11),'NONE') AS 'Julia'

    ,CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('REF', T0.COMMENTS, 1) > 1 THEN REF
        ELSE 'NONE'
    END 

FROM ODLN T0  INNER JOIN DLN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 

WHERE 
T0.[CardCode] = 'aa28' and  T0.[NumAtCard] Like 'SP%%%%%%%%%%%'
```